# Complex indexing of a multidimensional array with indices of lower dimensional arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, numpy-slicing

**Problem:**

- I have a numpy array of 4 dimensions:

  ```py
  x = np.arange(1000).reshape(5, 10, 10, 2 )
  ```

  If we print it:

  [image]
- I want to find the *indices of the 6 largest values of the array in the 2nd axis but **only** for the 0th element in the last axis* (red circles in the image):

  ```py
  indLargest2ndAxis = np.argpartition(x[...,0], 10-6, axis=2)[...,10-6:]
  ```

  These indices have a shape of (5,10,6) as expected.
- I want to obtain the *values of the array for these indices in the 2nd axis but now for the 1st element in the last axis* (yellow circles in the image). They should have a shape of (5,10,6). Without vectorizing, this could be done with:

  ```py
  np.array([ [ [ x[i, j, k, 1] for k in indLargest2ndAxis[i,j]] for j in range(10) ] for i in range(5) ])
  ```

  However, I would like to achieve it vectorizing. I tried indexing with:

  ```py
  x[indLargest2ndAxis, 1]
  ```

  But I get `IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5`. **How can I manage this indexing combination in a vectorized way?**

Comment: `np.argpartition` "returns an array of indices of the same shape as `a` that _index data along the given axis_ in partitioned order." So a first naive attempt would be to use an ellipsis `x[..., indLargest2ndAxis, 1]`. That said, I'm not quite clear what you mean by "display the values [...] for the 1st element in the last axis". Is it simply another slice? In this case, fancy indexing (advanced indexing).

Comment: Also note that `np.argpartition(x[..., 0], 6, ...)` may not do what you expect; It will yield indexes that would partition `x[...,0]` such that - along the axis with index 2 - `x[..., 6, 0]` is in it's sorted position, the elements before it are smaller, and the elements after are larger. If `x[...,6,0]` is indeed the (unique) 6th largest value of the array you can then retrieve the 6 largest elements via `x[..., 6:, 0]`; otherwise, you may not always get the 6 largest values.

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger Ah, I got mixed up with largest and smallest, I think now `indLargest2ndAxis` should hold the index of the 6 largest values of `x[...,0]` along the 2nd axis.

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger Yes, my question is how to do this advanced indexing. `indLargest2ndAxis` holds the indices of the 0, 1 and 2 axis of `x` while the 3rd axis should be `1`. I don't understand why writing directly `x[indLargest2ndAxis, 1]` does not work, but `x[..., indLargest2ndAxis, 1]` produces a result. What happens when you write `...`? But also, this expression does not give the results I wanted: it has a shape of (5, 10, 5, 10, 6), but I wanted (5, 10, 6), with the values given by the yellow circles of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I think I now get what you are after. Fancy indexing is [documented here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) in detail. Be warned though that - in its full generality - this is quite heavy stuff. In a nutshell, fancy indexing allows you to take elements from a source array (according to some `idx`) and place them into a new array (fancy indexing *allways* returns a copy):

```py
source = np.array([10.5, 21, 42])
idx = np.array([0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0])

# this is fancy indexing
target = source[idx]

expected = np.array([10.5, 21, 42, 21, 21, 21, 42, 21, 10.5])
assert np.allclose(target, expected)
```

What is nice about this is that you can control the shape of the resulting array using the shape of the index array:

```py
source = np.array([10.5, 21, 42])
idx = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 2]])

target = source[idx]

expected = np.array([[10.5, 21], [21, 42]])
assert np.allclose(target, expected)
assert target.shape == (2,2)
```

Where things get a little more interesting is if `source` has more than one dimension. In this case, you need to specify the indices of each axis so that numpy knows which elements to take:

```py
source = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
idxA = np.array([0, 1])
idxB = np.array([0, 1])

# this will take (0,0) and (1,1)
target = source[idxA, idxB]

expected = np.array([0, 3])
assert np.allclose(target, expected)
```

Observe that, again, the shape of `target` matches the shape of the index used.   What is awesome about fancy indexing is that index shapes are broadcasted if necessary:

```py
source = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
idxA = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1]).reshape((4,1))
idxB = np.array([0, 1]).reshape((1,2))

target = source[idxA, idxB]

expected = np.array([[0, 1],[0, 1],[2, 3],[2, 3]])
assert np.allclose(target, expected)
```

At this point, you can understand where your exception comes from. Your `source.ndim` is `4`; however, you try to index it with a 2-tuple `(indLargest2ndAxis, 1)`. Numpy will interpret this as you trying to index the first axis using `indLargest2ndAxis`, the second axis using `1`, and all other axis using `:`. Clearly, this doesn't work. All values of `indLargest2ndAxis` would have to be between `0` and `4` (inclusive), since they would have to refer to positions along the first axis of `x`.

What my suggestion of `x[..., indLargest2ndAxis, 1]` does is tell numpy that you wish to index the last two axes of `x`, i.e., you wish to index the third axis using `indLargest2ndAxis`, the fourth axis using `1`, and `:` for anything else.

This will produce a result since all elements of `indLargest2ndAxis` are in `[0, 10)`, but will produce a shape of `(5, 10, 5, 10, 6)` (which is not what you want). Being a bit hand-wavy, the first part of the shape `(5, 10)` comes from the ellipsis (`...`), aka. select everything, the middle part `(5, 10, 6)` comes from `indLargest2ndAxis` selecting elements along the third axis of `x` according to the shape of `indLargest2ndAxis` and the final part (which you don't see because it is squeezed) comes from selecting index `1` along the fourth axis.

---

Moving on to your actual problem, you can entirely dodge the fancy indexing bullet and do the following:

```py
x = np.arange(1000).reshape(5, 10, 10, 2)
order = x[..., 0]
values = x[..., 1]
idx = np.argpartition(order, 4)[..., 4:]
result = np.take_along_axis(values, idx, axis=-1)
```

**Edit:** Of course, you can also use fancy indexing; however, it is more cryptic and doesn't scale as nicely to different shapes:

```py
x = np.arange(1000).reshape(5, 10, 10, 2)
indLargest2ndAxis = np.argpartition(x[..., 0], 4)[..., 4:]
result = x[np.arange(5)[:, None, None], np.arange(10)[None, :, None], indLargest2ndAxis, 1]
```

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you a lot! I had read a bit about advanced slicing but I hadn't been able to completely understand it. Now I think I have finally managed. I just suggested a minor reorder that I think is easier to understand.

Comment: Also, in case it may help someone, I found in this problem the advanced indexing was a bit faster taking in my computer 6.0 µs, while `np.take_along_axis` took 9.6 µs.

Comment: @Puco4 Thanks for the compliment. Please remember to mark the answer as correct if it answers the question.